# In Ionic 3 on Android, the app Running if phone is locked in background. app is active when the device locked

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

(Note: I do know that same question is asked for ionic version 2 but has no answers)

Currently, if the phone goes to sleep with the app active, when the phone wakes up and is locked, the app is visible in the background .

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node : v6.10.3
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 10
```

Comment: Any screenshots?

Comment: thing is app runs normally without any issue but when i go back or exit app or opens any inappbrowser it show lock screen i have used   this.onPauseSubscription = platform.pause.subscribe(() => {

      
});  to check weather android running ornot it show like app is running but android activity paused (phone locked)